# GraphQL SPQR - How to get the list of the fields were requested by client using a query

Tags: graphql-spqr

is there a way to retrieve the list of the fields were requested in a GraphQL query by a client?

Lets assume I have the following types:

```html
type Book {

  isbn: String
  title: String
  genre: String
  author: Author
}

type Author {

  name: String
  surname: String
  age: Int
}
```

Is there a way on Java side inside a method annotated with @GraphQLQuery to know the fields were requested by the client?

For example, having the following queries:

```html
query {

  book ( isbn = "12345" ) {
  
    title
    genre
  }
}

query {

  book ( isbn = "12345" ) {
  
    title
    author {
    
      name
      surname
    }
  }
}
```

I can know the first query requested the fields title and genre of Book
and the second required title from Book and also name and surname of the Author ?

Thanks
Massimo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain this info via `@GraphQLEnvironment`. If you just need the immediate subfields, you can inject the names like this:

```
@GraphQLQuery
public Book book(String isbn, @GraphQLEnvironment Set<String> subfields) {
    ...
}
```

If you want all the subfields, or other selection info, you can inject `ResolutionEnvironment` and get `DataFetcherEnvironment` from there. That in turn gives you access to the whole `SelectionSet`.

```
@GraphQLQuery
public Book book(String isbn, @GraphQLEnvironment ResolutionEnvironment env) {
    DataFetchingFieldSelectionSet selection = env.dataFetchingEnvironment.getSelectionSet();
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kaqqao, it works !

My intent was to extract the required fields in order to build dynamic entity graphs and use them with the underlying DB doing only the required joins based on what the client wants.

I've got an implementation already :)

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing that in action, if there's anything you can share :)

Comment: Here is the Github repo (only a training POC in order to explore GraphQL features):
https://github.com/m-daros/graphql-spring-boot.  You can find the code that is based on your hints in this class: https://github.com/m-daros/graphql-spring-boot/blob/master/src/main/java/mdaros/training/graphql/spring/boot/service/AbstractService.java. :).  You can run the application and try some query using the GUI http://localhost:8080/gui